# How to migrate tasks from Thunderbird calendar to Jira?

Tags: thunderbird, jira

How can I migrate my tasks from my Thunderbird calendar to Jira?

Comment: See [my own answer](https://superuser.com/a/1706805/347842). I [shared my knowledge, Q&A-style](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your tasks are in an `.ics` file (a calendar you have subsribed to), create a new local calendar in Thunderbird. Then, import the tasks into that calendar. (`Events and tasks | Import...`)

Thunderbird stores the calendar data of local calendars in your profile folder in the file `calendar-data/local.sqlite`, an SQLite database file.

Close Thunderbird, so all data is flushed to that database file.

Open the database file in an SQLite client, e.g. the Firefox add-on [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager-webext).

If you only need to migrate creation time, modified time, title, start date, due date and description, you can execute the folllowing SQL query. If you need location, categories, attachments or more, it will be more complicated.

```sql
select
'Task' as issuetype,
datetime(t.time_created / 1000000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') as time_created,
datetime(t.last_modified / 1000000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') as last_modified,
t.title, 
datetime(t.todo_entry / 1000000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') as start, 
datetime(t.todo_due / 1000000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') as due, 
p.value as description
from cal_todos t left
outer join cal_properties p
on t.id = p.item_id and p.key = 'DESCRIPTION'
-- where t.todo_completed is null -- filter open tasks only
```

Export the query result to a CSV file.

SQLite Manager fails to escape line breaks, so you may need to do that manually by adding quotes.

In Jira `Settings | System | Import and Export | External System Import`, choose `CSV` and configure the import according to this excerpt from my saved import configuration:

```json
{
  ...
  "config.field.mappings" : {
    "issuetype" : {
      "jira.field" : "issuetype",
      "userChanged" : "true",
      "manualMapping" : "false"
    },
    "due" : {
      "jira.field" : "duedate",
      "userChanged" : "true",
      "manualMapping" : "false"
    },
    "start" : {
      "jira.field" : "startdate",
      "userChanged" : "true",
      "manualMapping" : "false",
    },
    "time_created" : {
      "jira.field" : "created",
      "userChanged" : "true",
      "manualMapping" : "false"
    },
    "description" : {
      "jira.field" : "description",
      "userChanged" : "true",
      "manualMapping" : "false"
    },
    "title" : {
      "jira.field" : "summary",
      "userChanged" : "true",
      "manualMapping" : "false"
    },
    "last_modified" : {
      "jira.field" : "updated",
      "userChanged" : "true",
      "manualMapping" : "false"
    }
  },
  ...
  "config.delimiter" : ",",
  ...
  "config.date.format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
}
```